# Comparing two extracted values(month and year) with other extracted values from a date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, stored-procedures

I was trying in my stored procedure in Oracle to compare two numbers (both extracted from a `DATE` with `EXTRACT` function) with 2 more numbers (extracted with `EXTRACT`), and I wanted to check if I already have a row with the same month and year, but no matter what I do, I always find a row EVEN THO THE MONTH AND THE YEAR IS DIFFERENT!
Here's my code below that I tested outside my stored procedure, and the `DBMS_OUTPUT` always prints 1 occurence found in my `SELECT COUNT(*)`:

```
DECLARE
    VAR_COUNTER NUMBER;
    VAR_MONTH NUMBER;
    VAR_YEAR NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('10/12/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')),EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('10/12/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')) 
   INTO VAR_MONTH,VAR_YEAR FROM DUAL;

   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   INTO VAR_COUNTER 
   FROM FATTURATO_RISTORANTI
   WHERE FATTURATO_RISTORANTI.ID_RISTORANTE = 3
         AND FATTURATO_RISTORANTI.MESE= VAR_MONTH 
         AND FATTURATO_RISTORANTI.ANNO = VAR_YEAR;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VAR_MONTH || ' ' || VAR_YEAR || ' ' || VAR_COUNTER);
END;
```

P.S. : mese is the extracted `MONTH` and anno is the extracted `YEAR`;

Comment: `TO_DATE('10/12/2019','DD/MM/YY')` should be `TO_DATE('10/12/2019','DD/MM/YYYY')`. Also, you'd better call your variables differently, to avoid issues with what is a variable and what is a column

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the problem, I tried changing like you said but I still get at least 1 occurrence even tho the month/year is different

Comment: I will make the code more readable, gimme 1 minute

Comment: I see it now: `FATTURATO_RISTORANTI.ANNO = mese` :)

Comment: That's not the problem either, it was just a typo here, I still find 1 occurrence

Comment: What if you run the query with hardcoded values?

Comment: if I manually type 12 and 2019, I get  0 occurrences (which is correct), but if I get those values from a DATE with the EXTRACT function, it doesn't work

Comment: Have you edited the format mask (yyyy)? I don't see any other issue here

Comment: Yeah I did, but still to no avail

Comment: Aside from having `VAR_MONTH` twice (but I think you've just changed the names for posting) what you've got now works, so it either seems to be a data problem - that you really do have a row with that year/month (maybe uncommitted changes are tripping you up?) - or more likely your real code is still using variables called `mese` and `anno`, which cnoflict with the table columns - as Aleksej pointed out in the first comment.

Comment: At this point I'm completely lost...I even tried changing the table completely and using a `CHAR` that contains the date in the format `MM/YYYY`, but still I get an occurrence...I really don't understand

Comment: Can you build a test table with some data, to help us to replicate what 's happening? As is, it's really hard to see what's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the values only once you can also write

```
DECLARE
    contatore NUMBER;
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO contatore
      FROM FATTURATO_RISTORANTI
     WHERE FATTURATO_RISTORANTI.ID_RISTORANTE = 3
           AND FATTURATO_RISTORANTI.MESE = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '2019-12-10')
           AND FATTURATO_RISTORANTI.ANNO = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE '2019-12-10');

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(contatore);
END;
```

Or use

```
vMese := EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('10/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
vAnno := EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('10/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

`FATTURATO_RISTORANTI.ID_RISTORANTE = 3` is equal to `3 = FATTURATO_RISTORANTI.ID_RISTORANTE` but more "common readable".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, now it's all about figuring out why it always finds an occurrence even tho month and year are different :')

Answer (score 0):

This should be like:

```
DECLARE
    contatore                                NUMBER;
    vMese                                    NUMBER;
    vAnno                                    NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE('10/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY')), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('10/12/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
      INTO vMese, vAnno
      FROM DUAL;

    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO contatore
      FROM FATTURATO_RISTORANTI
     WHERE     3 = FATTURATO_RISTORANTI.ID_RISTORANTE
           AND FATTURATO_RISTORANTI.MESE = vMese
           AND FATTURATO_RISTORANTI.ANNO = vAnno;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vMese || ' ' || vAnno || ' ' || contatore);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I apparently solved my problem by NOT using a variable, instead of using mese and anno, I just gave the parameter that the table needed, I still don't know why it works like this, I need to investigate!

Comment: You've been told that using variables called `mese` and `anno` would cause this problem ([same as this, coincidentally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51308379/266304)) and you said you'd changed the variable names, so this is a bit confusing... Also if you are using Wernfried's approach (which is what this sounds like?) then you should upvote/accept that, rather than leaving this - which doesn't really answer your question, or at least not in a way that is likely to help anyone else.