# Why I get two different result from same query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I create a function which return does user email exist or not

```
FUNCTION USER_EXISTS(email IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS 
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    /*userExists*/
BEGIN
  OPEN rc FOR
       SELECT count(*) as does_user_exist
        FROM users 
            WHERE Email  
                 LIKE '%' || email || '%';
  RETURN rc;
END USER_EXISTS;
```

And the problem which I notice is that when I call this function I get result that `72` user exists with this email address

```
SELECT USER_PACKAGE.USER_EXISTS('%zl%') FROM DUAL
```

[image]

But when I call `SELECT` statment like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS WHERE Email LIKE '%zl%'
```

I get result

[image]

WHat is wrong here ? Where did I made mistake ?

Comment: why are you using sys_refcursor for the function ? just make a count for the records that match the condition

Comment: Apart from returning a ref cursor, which may or may not be a problem for you, the difference in the count - 72 vs 1 - [is because of a name clash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51308379/266304).

Comment: Congraduation ! You are right. I solve problem :) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the function is wrong, as it is a sys_refcursor object that goes for the whole table.

You don't need a sys_refcursor object in that function, just a normal count will work.

Example

```
SQL> create table tb_users ( id number generated by default on null as identity ( start with 1 increment by 1 ) , email varchar2(100) ) ;

SQL> insert into tb_users ( email ) values ( 'example1@z1.goo.com' ) ;

SQL> insert into tb_users ( email ) values ( 'example1@z2.goo.com' ) ;

SQL> commit ;

Table created.

1 row created.

1 row created.

Commit complete.

SQL> select count(*) from tb_users where email like '%z1%' ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> create or replace FUNCTION USER_EXISTS(email IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
    rc  SYS_REFCURSOR;
    /*userExists*/
BEGIN
  OPEN rc FOR
       SELECT count(*) as does_user_exist
        FROM tb_users
            WHERE Email
                 LIKE '%' || email || '%';
  RETURN rc;
 END USER_EXISTS;
 /

Function created.

SQL> select user_exists('%z1%') from dual ;

USER_EXISTS('%Z1%')
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

DOES_USER_EXIST
---------------
              2
```

The rc returns 1 for each record count in the table. So, you probably have 72 records in your table, that is the reason for 72.

Update

A function like this would work better in your scenario

```
SQL> create or replace FUNCTION USER_EXISTS(pemail IN VARCHAR2)  RETURN number
is
rc number;
BEGIN
     SELECT count(*) into rc FROM tb_users
            WHERE Email
                 LIKE '%' || pemail || '%';
  RETURN rc;
  9  END USER_EXISTS;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL> select USER_EXISTS(pemail => 'z1') from dual ;

USER_EXISTS(PEMAIL=>'Z1')
-------------------------
                        1

SQL>
```

Comment: Why you then use SYS_REFCURSOR in answer ?

Comment: I was just showing you why the function works in the way it does

Comment: I updated the post with a better function for your purposes

Comment: Again I get same result

Comment: what do you mean you get the same  result ? with my new function ?

Comment: how are you calling the new function ? can you update the question and provide the output of the new function ?